# Problems by creating Multiple PDFs

Tags: c#, loops

I succeeded in creating a single pdf, but how can I design a loop for file names?
The Problem is every Loop my file will be overwritten

I tried to add a variable to the file, but it doesn't work:

```
var filename = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) 
    + strGPNrVar + DateTime.Now + "Report.pdf";
```

Here's the code so far:

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "/Report.pdf", FileMode.Create));

PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(5);
document.Opem();

foreach (var f in transactions)
{
      //MessageBox.Show("Das ist die Menge" + f.CurrencyAmount);

      table.AddCell(f.ID.ToString());
      table.AddCell(f.TransactionType);
      table.AddCell(f.UserName);
      table.AddCell(f.EuroAmount);
      table.AddCell(f.GPNummer);


      document.Add(table);

}

document.Close();

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "/Report.pdf");
MessageBox.Show("Pdfs erfolgreich erstellt");
```

I need to loop this for every customer. The filename should be astring GpNrvar and also datetime.now

Comment: What did not work with your attempt? Might you be missing a slash after the desktop path?

Comment: How do you know which customer you are downloading? What is `GpNrvar`?

Comment: the code is working for one customer but it will be overwritten everytime...
I need to create for every customer a transaction list.
gpNrVar will be iterated from 1 to 5000 
Gp Nr var is the filter for transactionlist.
and every number except 0 list should get a transactionpdf

Comment: Read up on `Path.Combine`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said "it doesn't work", but you didn't describe why it doesn't work.  If you tell us what happened we can better help you solve the problem.  However I think your issue is the default formatting of dates contains characters that are in the list of invalid filename characters.

Your code uses `DateTime.Now` by directly adding it to a string:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) 
+ strGPNrVar+ DateTime.Now + "Report.pdf";
```

This is identical to saying:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) 
+ strGPNrVar + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "Report.pdf";
```

Notice the `ToString()` part - a `DateTime` value needs to be converted to a string and the default format usually includes slashes and colons, both not allowed in a filename [on Windows filesystems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file).  In your case, (if `strGPNrVar` is "123") you will end up with a filename like this (on a system in the US):

```
C:\Users\YourUsername\Desktop1237/22/2019 9:46:06 PMReport.pdf
```

You need to manually specify the date format to get rid of the invalid characters.  The second problem this illustrates, as others have pointed out, you should use `Path.Combine` to combine directory paths and filenames - this will take care of adding slashes where they are needed:

```
var filename = 
    Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), 
  strGPNrVar + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-hh.mm.ss")
  + $"_Report.pdf");
```

Comment: I suspect he wants `Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), strGPNrVar ... + $"_{i}_Report.pdf")`

Comment: The Problem is not the overlapping, because strGPNrVar, will be iterated every loop.
I dont know the syntax for creating this file. It says everytime the path could not be find. Because it thinks the path should be e.g. Desktop/2130
So I cant create a dynamic filename

Comment: Thanks @DourHighArch - totally missed that!  Cryptogear, take a look at the edit - this should fix it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, you helped me a lot!
This is the Code that works for me:

```
var pdf1 =
            Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop),
            strGPNrVar + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-hh.mm.ss")
            + $"_Report.pdf");
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(pdf1, FileMode.Create,
            FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
           {

            Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);
```